# PHP/HTML link with some forms filled on that page?

Tags: php, html

I'm writing a webpage in HTML/PHP. My index.html has a form with several inputs, including name and profession, that gets passed to PHP/MySQL (process.php). After interfacing with the database, I want a button at the bottom of the process.php page that links back to index.html that shows the the 'name' and 'profession' fields based on the previous entry. I'm using transactions through MySQL to avoid multiple users getting each other's previous submissions back, but I can't seem to figure out how to send information back to index.html. Any help would be great, and let me know if I was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can create session variables to hold name and profession

```
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
$_SESSION['profession'] = $profession;
```

Change your index file to index.php

Answer (score 0):

in process.php put a form and hidden input(s)

```
 <FORM ...>
 <input type="hidden" mane="name" value="$NAME VARIABLE">
 <input type="hidden" mane="profession" value=$PROFESSION VARIABLE>
 <input type=submit value="Go Back">
```

You may get the variables  either from the submitted data  or from sql query.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a form with the button in it and pass the variables that way or using a link instead of a button pass the parameters in a URL style.

**Option 1:**

```
<form action="page.php">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php name ?>" name="username"/>
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php profession ?>" name="profession"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Next Page" />
</form>
```

**Option 2:**

```
<a href="page.php?name=<?php name?>&profession=<?php profession?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need this information to be secure (like a password or something) you can also use cookies to avoid even having to start a session on the server.

```
$_COOKIE['name'] = $name;
$_COOKIE['profession'] = $profession;
```

Then you read it in the index page using

```
$name = $_COOKIE['name'];
$profession = $_COOKIE['profession'];
```